# Почему STMFD и LDMFD работают с разными регистрами?

Tags: ассемблер, компиляция, arm

Инструкция `STMFD` сохранила в стеке `R4` и `LR`, а восстанавливаются во время исполнения `LDMFD` регистры `R4` и `PC`:

```
            main
                STMFD SP!, {R4,LR}
                ADR R0, aHelloWorld
                BL __2printf
.text:0000000C  MOV R0, #0
                LDMFD SP!, {R4,PC}
```

Компилятор: Keil Release 6/2013 (режим ARM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LR` (Link Register) содержит адрес возврата из процедуры. При входе его сохраняем на стеке (т.е. в оперативной памяти) с помощью `STM`. В конце процедуры нужно произвести возврат. Это делается путем считывания сохраненного значения `LR` в `PC` т.е. `Program Counter`.

Запись значения в `PC` эквивалентна безусловному переходу. Т.е. это и есть возврат по адресу, который изначально хранился в `LR` при входе в `main`.

Все время пока выполняется функция `main` регистром `LR` можно пользоваться, т.к. значение из него уже сохранилось на стеке. Именно для этого и нужна инструкция `STM` в самом начале, чтобы не потерять значение адреса возврата и освободить регистры (а данном случае `R4` и `LR`) для использования внутри `main`.

Comment: Как я понял, в регистре ```LR``` обычно сохраняется адрес места, куда нужно всякой функции вернуть управление. А что если моя функция ```main()``` позже будет сама пользоваться этим регистром в момент вызова например ```printf()```? И посредством ```BL``` я занес в регистр адрес 0xC (который отсылает на инструкцию, предшествующей инструкции ```LDMFD```). Разве не должна программа выпадать в бесконечный цикл, возвращаясь по адресу, расположенному перед возвращением (перед ```LDMFD```)?

Comment: Для наглядности редактировал основной вопрос

Comment: Сохранение на стеке (т.е. в памяти) и нужно, чтобы регистр можно было использовать. Дополнил ответ.